# what does “D = diag(W.1)” means?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix

[image: what does “D = diag(W.1)” means?], what does “D = diag(W.1)” means?on page #2, just below equation (6)
PFA screenshot and here is the link of the paper -
[original paper](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/Aging_KDD2015_camera-ready.pdf)

Comment: X-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3289370/339790

Comment: It already has answers there, please don't cross-post. That way, you don't waste people's time.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that $\mathbf W\cdot \mathbf 1$ denotes a matrix-vector product of a matrix $\mathbf W$ with a vector of ones $\mathbf 1$ of the corresponding size (number of columns).

The result of this operation is a vector (of the size of number of rows of $\mathbf W$), so, it makes total sense to apply a diagonal function on it to arrive to a matrix form.

Disclaimer: my assumption is based solely on reading the formula at question, and not looking at the rest of the paper at all.